# asp.net webservice jquery textbox autocomplete

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I'm trying to implement jquery - textbox autocomplete. for this setup a web service.

```
    [WebMethod]


    public List<Condition> GetCondition(string term)
    {


        List<Condition> listCondition = new List<Condition>();

        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db5"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spSelCondition", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@term",
                Value = term
            });
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                listCondition.Add(new Condition { ConditionID = rdr["ConditionID"].ToString(), ConditionName = rdr["ConditionName"].ToString() });
            }
            return listCondition;
        }
    }

    public class Condition
    {
        public string ConditionName { get; set; }
        public string ConditionID { get; set; }
    }
```

WebService works perfectly fine. To populate the textbox with jquery autocomplete this javascript I've written.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#txtCondition').autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'ibs_ws.asmx/GetCondition',
                            method: 'post',
                            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                            data: JSON.stringify({ term: request.term }),
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function (data) {
                                response(data.d);


                            },
                            error: function (err) {
                                alert(err);
                            }
                        });
                    }

            });
        })</script>
```

When I access the webservice it takes the @term as parameter and returns the result with ConditionID and ConditionName in xml formate. But on the webform when I give type anything in the textbox it alerts with [object object].

What could be the problem.

--
Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

May be it will help you. try this

I think you need to use $.map(data.d, function (value, key) {}).  here is the example need to update your success code like below then you can get value inside object.

```
success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (value, key) {
                            return {
                                ConID: value.ConditionID,
                                ConNAme: value.ConditionName,
                            }
                        }))
                    },
```

AS you said your service returns conditionID and Name so i used these variable you can match what it returns exactly.